My scrollView compnent is not working despite all the online solutions
I recently started learning react native and i have been going through some styling problems nad tailwind conversion of code but leaving that i am facing a more irritating issue... My scrollView tag is not scrolling...
import { ScrollView, View, Text } from "react-native";
import React from "react";
import { SafeAreaView } from "react-native-safe-area-context";

const Home = () => {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView className=" flex-1">
      <ScrollView
        contentContainerStyle={{
          display: "flex",
          height: "100%",
          alignItems: "center",
          padding: 8,
          margin: 2,
          flex: 1,
          flexGrow: 1,
          marginHorizontal: 20,
        }}
      >
        <View className=" w-screen h-[500px] items-center mt-1">
          <View className="bg-pink-300 h-2/5 w-11/12 m-1 rounded-lg items-center">
            <Text className="text-center text-2xl font-black text-black">
              graph of payment made recently
            </Text>
          </View>
          <View className="bg-slate-300 h-2/5 w-11/12 m-1 rounded-lg items-center">
            <Text className="text-center text-2xl font-black text-black">
              recent payments made
            </Text>
          </View>
          <View className="bg-slate-300 h-2/5 w-11/12 m-1 rounded-lg items-center">
            <Text className="text-center text-2xl font-black text-black">
              recent payments made
            </Text>
          </View>
          <View className="bg-slate-300 h-2/5 w-11/12 m-1 rounded-lg items-center">
            <Text className="text-center text-2xl font-black text-black">
              recent payments made
            </Text>
          </View>
          <View className="bg-slate-300 h-2/5 w-11/12 m-1 rounded-lg items-center">
            <Text className="text-center text-2xl font-black text-black">
              recent payments made
            </Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default Home;


this is my home page in the route (tabs). I have gone through so many stack overflow question, so many other websites but none of the solution are working. I also note that most of them are talking about changing the  flex settings and other stuff.

I expected the scroll window to scroll when i added the scrollView tag to the app but i didnt get that when i run on android studio i can see that a scrollbar is formed but its not getting used.
Pls Help i am losing hair over this (mostly its gonna be some stupid thing i didnt add)
Thanks in advanced

Can you add a screenshot of the screen because it doesn't seem like there is much content for the scrollview to make the content scrollable. It doesn't scroll if the scrollable content is easily fitting inside the scrollview.

done. Uploaded the photo

Try adding marginBottom to the main view in which all these four views are present and see if it works.

nope not working

I checked your code again and the guy above was right, first, remove height from scrollView and then remove height from the View enclosing all the views inside. It is restricting the scroll view and you can remove display: "flex" too as it is not really required in react-native.

This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post; instead, provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker. - From Review

I ran your code in React Native, and here are the adjustments you should make to the ScrollView style:
<SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1}}>
  <ScrollView
    style={{
      padding: 8,
      margin: 2,
      flex: 1,
      marginHorizontal: 20,
    }}>

  </ScrollView>
</SafeAreaView>

Additionally, remove the fixed height of the container (h-[500px]). Instead of using a percentage for height (h-2/5), provide a numeric value for height. This approach ensures better compatibility and responsiveness across different devices.

In content container style never give hight or flex. It'll stop scrolling
modify your content container style as below:
  <ScrollView
    contentContainerStyle={{
      display: "flex",
      alignItems: "center",
      padding: 8,
      margin: 2,
      flexGrow: 1,
      marginHorizontal: 20,
    }}


nope not working
